# Редирект на имя с первой буквой в нижнем регистре

Tags: nginx, редирект

Как сделать редирект в nginx с большой буквы на маленькую, после хоста?

Для примера: `http://host/Help` нужно перенаправить на `http://host/help`

`http://host/HelpMe` нужно перенаправить на `http://host/helpMe`

Comment: `location = /Help { rewrite ^ /help permanent; }`

Comment: а в общем случае: https://dodwell.us/rewrite-uri-to-lowercase-using-nginxperl-nginxlua-or-apache